# How can i get this method from JQuery ui tab which is loaded by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, tabs

I am using [jquery ui tab](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax) to load a html, in that html i have a method.

```
$("#tabs").tabs({               
                beforeLoad: function (event, ui) {
                    ui.jqXHR.error(function () {
                        ui.panel.html(
                          "Couldn't load this tab. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. " +
                          "If this wouldn't be a demo.");
                    });
                    ui.jqXHR.success(function () {
                        alertMe()
                    });
                }
            });

<div id="tabs" style="height: 100%">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="Map.html">Tab 1</a></li>
        </ul>
 </div>
```

Inside the map.html i have the alertMe method. here it show alertMe  is undifined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jqXHR 'success' is called when the server returns the response successfully, but before any tab rendering logic happens (like adding the html/js to the page). So a better solution would be to use the load method of the tabs control to handle the call:

```
$('tab's).tabs({
    beforeLoad: ...
    load: function() {
       alertMe(); // Global JS on loaded fragment will be available on page now
    }
});
```

API Docs: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load